# Vue.js object mapping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, templates

i have such object

```
data: () => ({
            customer: {
                item: {
                    name: undefined
                }}
})
```

in the template I'm using

```
<v-number
separator="."
decimal="2"
group-by="3"
error-text="system.global.cusotmer"
v-model="customer.item.name"
></v-number>
```

but i get an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
> of undefined"

what i'm doing wrong?

this works fine:

```
data: () => ({
            customer: {
                item: undefined}
})
v-model="customer.item"
```

Comment: Do you get this data from the server? The data could take some time to load and accessing `customer.item.name` before it loads could throw an error.

Comment: no, the user must be input the number in this v-number, and after i need to get this whole object to the backend

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```js
data() {
  return {
    customer: {
      item: {
        name: undefined
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Also, please provide more context on what `v-model` is applied to and what your template is actually doing.